# Sql SubSelect With Multiple Keys

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, subquery

I am trying to copy rows from 1 table to a copy of itself, but only including rows for accounts that exist in a 2nd table.

This works fine with just one key field (account) as below:

```
insert into newlibr.acpmstpf
select * from oldlibr.acpmstpf as source
where not exists
(select *
 from newlibr.acpmstpf as target
 where target.acpno    = source.acpno
   and target.acpbrn   = source.acpbrn
   and target.acpitm   = source.acpitm)
 and source.acpno in (select account from accinfo)
```

In this case I am trying to insert rows from the original table acpmstpf in schema oldlibr to a copy of itself in newlibr, matching rows on the 2 keys account/branch (acpno/acpbrn) and ONLY inserting those rows where the account is in 2nd table accinfo.

What I REALLY want to do is to ONLY insert those rows where the account & branch are in accinfo, because if only 2 branches are in accinfo and there are 100 on acpmstpf, it copies all 100 rows.

I know I could do this with a join, but then I would have to specify all the columns (which could be many - I have this scenario for a few tables).

Is there a way I could do this and still use a sub-select?

Comment: With SQL questions *always* tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, didn't think of that but it's actually DB2.

Comment: Okay, I've added the tag for you.

Comment: DB2 is special, since the various platforms are different.  I added the db2400 tag for you.

Comment: Thanks for adding the tags. Again Stackoverflow users come up with the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace

```
and source.acpno in (select account from accinfo)
```

and look for tuples (account, branch) instead. Many DBMS support this:

```
and (source.acpno, source.acpbrn) in (select account, branch from accinfo)
```

For those DBMS that don't, you'd have to resort to `EXISTS`:

```
and exists
(
  select * 
  from accinfo
  where accinfo.account = source.acpno
    and accinfo.branch = source.branch
)
```

Comment: I didn't know about tuples, that works perfectly for DB2 (IBM iSeries), thanks very much.  1 account has over 100 branches and maybe only 20 on our 2nd table, but the main table we are pulling over could have thousands of rows for each branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
insert into newlibr.acpmstpf
    select *
    from oldlibr.acpmstpf as source
    where not exists (select 1
                      from newlibr.acpmstpf as target
                      where target.acpno = source.acpno and
                            target.acpbrn = source.acpbrn
                            target.acpitm = source.acpitm
                     ) and
           exists (select 1
                   from accinfo a
                   where source.acpno = a.accinfo and
                         source.acpbrn = a.acpbrn
                  );
```